# XPATH for an XML with multiple labels

Tags: xpath

I have below XML and I want to get an XPATH for the label elements -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<perf-config>
    <server name="Server1" version="V2" />
    <performance-data>
    <buttons>YES</buttons>
    <metric id="8D1180" description="response time " type="multi" listtype="P" >
        <timerange localstart="20180727110300" localend="20180727110400" utcstart="20180727090300" utcend="20180727090400"/>
        <scroll prev="20180727110230" next="20180727110430"/>
        <gathererinterval seconds="60"/>
        <data-range seconds="60"/>
        <row label="stc01" value="0.19" per="100" ex="NONE"/>
        <row label="stc02" value="0.097" per="51.0526" ex="NONE"/>
        <row label="stc03.1" value="0.01" per="5.26316" ex="NONE"/>
        <row label="stc03.2" value="0.001" per="0.526316" ex="NONE"/>
    </metric>
    </performance-data>
</perf-config>What would be XPATH for label stc01, stc02...
```

I tried below, but not helped.

```
/perf-config/performance-data/metric/label[text()='stc01']
```

I am able to get the xpath as below

```
/perf-config/performance-data/metric/row[@label="stc01"]
```

and the output comes as

> Element=`'<row ex="NONE" label="stc01" per="100" value="0.19"/>'`

Next I am looking at getting the data for "value" from this xpath

Comment: I am able to get the xpath as below
/perf-config/performance-data/metric/row[@label="stc01"]
and the output comes as - 
Element='<row ex="NONE" label="stc01" per="100" value="0.19"/>'

Next I am looking at getting the data for "value" from this xpath

Comment: Update your question with the same info as for now your goals are different in question and comment

Answer (score 2):

Try below XPath to get required output:

```
/perf-config/performance-data/metric/row[@label='stc01']/@value
```

Comment: Do you want the output as `"0.19"`?

Comment: Yes, getting output 0.19 would help

Comment: Did you try my XPath? It should return required value

Comment: @Rinku: Andersson has answered both your original and your follow-up questions.  Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) and then upvote his answer if it's helped.  Thanks.